# Is there any to hide the radio buttons but not the drop down list?

Tags: jquery

I have two radio buttons that I want to hide and just give the drop down list to the users to select from. Is it possible to hide the radio buttons completely without hiding the drop down list? `$("[name^=UseAllCodes]").parent().hide();` hides the dd list too.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="UseAllCodes" value="yes" checked  onClick="attReset();"> All<br>
<input type="radio" name="UseAllCodes" value="no" onClick="attReset();"  id="theseCodes"> These codes  <br>
<select name="handpick" onChange="attToggleAndReset();" size="10" multiple>
<option value="25248692">Code 1
<option value="25248693">Code 2
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sure, don't use `parent()`...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan that leaves the text for the radio buttons

Comment: You didn't say anything about the text in your question. You probably want to wrap each text and radio button in a `label` element, and give both of them the same class. Then just `$('.classYouUsed').hide();`. Using a `label` element would be better for accessibility anyway.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for the idea. tried this, it is giving me error. Not sure whats wrong. `$("[name^=UseAllCodes]").after($("<label />").addClass("SelAttCodes"); 
   $(".SelAttCodes").hide();`

Comment: Are you not able to edit the original html? I think that is what @MikeMcCaughan was suggesting, rather than dynamically add the `<label>` elements.

Comment: @JohnS thanks! Its giving me error on hide statement. "
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"  . Not sure whats wrong `$("[name^=UseAllCodes]").after($("<label />")
    $("[name^=UseAllCodes]").closest('label').hide();`

Comment: You are missing the second closing parenthesis for `after($("<label />"))`. But I deleted my earlier comment because I thought you were adding the label elements to the original html, not dynamically adding them. The way you are adding them, they will be empty. That is, they won't wrap anything. So hiding them won't do anything for you.

Comment: @JohnS I can't touch the original code. Trying to add the label & then class dynamically and then hiding as Mike suggested. Is that not right way of doing things with jquery?

Comment: You would have to get the label element to wrap the radio button and its text. That can be done, but it is more complicated than the code you are trying.

Comment: If you can't change the original code, that's important information to have in you question, as is the requirement that you want the text removed. Please [edit] your question to reflect all information needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the original HTML, but you don't mind removing the radio buttons, rather than hiding them, you could do the following:

```
var $select = $("[name=handpick]");
var $cell = $select.parent();
$select.detach();
$cell.empty().append($select);
```

This detaches the select element, then clears out the table cell, and finally puts the select element back.

---

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17oxs3os/1/)

If you still need the radio buttons to process the values, you could replace them with a hidden input.

```
var $radio = $('#theseCodes');
var radioValue = $radio.val();
var radioName = $radio.attr('name');
var $cell = $radio.closest('td');
var $select = $cell.find('select');
$select.detach();
$cell.empty().append('<input type="hidden" name="' + radioName + '" value="' + radioValue + '" />').append($select);
```

If you were to post the form with the radio buttons hidden, their value would not be included, but the value of a hidden input would be.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17oxs3os/4/)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Except it also removed the drop down list. Sorry!

Comment: @Kaur - I added a jsfiddle showing it working. It does not remove the drop down list in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks again!

Comment: it worked perfectly for hiding, but empty method is leaving the user selection of 'thesecodes' element as NULL, which I need to have selected in order to process the multiple selections. This is blackbox code that I can't alter, that is why finding ways to take away user option of 'All' and setting default value to the second option. Is there a way to make that happen? thanks!

Comment: @Kaur - You could go back to trying to hide the radio buttons, or you could add a hidden input to replace the radio buttons. See my update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do this.

Add an **ID** or **class** to your radio button:

```
// Html
<input type="radio" id="myIdHere" .... />
<input type="radio" class="myClass" .... />

// JS
$("#myIdHere").hide()
$(".myClass").hide()
```

You could toggle by the input type:

```
$("input[type=radio]").hide()
```

Or you could be more specific and only toggle by the type inside the table:

```
$("table").find("input[type=radio]").hide()
```

There are probably a handful of other ways you can do this, just experiment a bit.